# Upgrade Devise for Rails

Tags: ruby, devise, rubygems, upgrade

I'm new to RoR and I don't know how to uninstall gems. I installed a version of devise that I don't want. I've already run the migration and devise_install, so  wondering if I just need to remove the files in my app and then run a gem removal, which I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Gemfile you should be able to set the version of devise you would like to upgrade to:

```
gem 'devise', '~> x.x.x'
```

then run `bundle update devise` to update the gem in your rails repo.

You should be able to re-run `rake generate devise:install` and it will create the necessary files again. Any conflicts will be printed to the console and you can remove the necessary files and rerun the task again.